# Run shell script from android application

Tags: android, shell, android-ndk

I have one shell script like this,

```
    #Script name : test.sh
    mkdir /boot
    mount -t vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /boot
    cp file1 /boot
    umount /boot

    mkdir -p /test1/test2/test3
    cp file2 /test1/test2
    cp file3 /test1/test2/test3
    STATUS=TRUE
```

Now this script is located in /test/ directory.
I am calling this script from a c function which is called from android application via jni.
I am using this function to call my script in C

```
void Java_com_ndkdemo_NDKdemoActivity_systemcall(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
    fp = popen(". /test/./test.sh; echo STATUS=$STATUS","r");
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof (buffer), fp) != 0)
    {
        LOGD("%s",buffer);
    }
}
```

Now when ever i call this systemcall function from my activity, it is not able to execute the commands inside the script test.sh
The same script is working if i am compiling a binary from normal C source code and execute that binary on console. I have tried to give permission with "chmod 777 /test/test.sh" but still it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell interpreter is `/system/bin/sh` then:

- for shell scripts that start with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), make it `#!/system/bin/sh`
- try to use the interpreter path itself instead of the `.` character to run your script

And it seems that [popen may not work in older versions of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910934/popen-on-android-ndk).

Comment: Yup tried this things too..but still not working, by the way what will the difference if i will use interpreter instead of . character? I am using this . because i need that STATUS variable in current console other wise i will not be able to use it.

Comment: Why do you need the STATUS variable? Maybe you can put it inside your test.sh and simplify your command, to minimize the places where a problem may appear.