# Application crashing on pclose

Tags: android, c, linux, file-io, pipe

I have an application that parses the output from a command line using `popen`. However, when tested on Android, it crashes on `pclose`: Why? When tested in other Unix environment I have no error...

```
char commandLine[256] = "ps -A | grep -c myApplication";

FILE * fPipe = popen(commandLine, "r");

if (fPipe == NULL)
    return 0;

int count = -1;
fscanf(fPipe, "%d", &count);

///If here I print count, I get zero, which is correct...

pclose(fPipe); ///Here it crashes!

return count;
```

**Update:** It seems that using `popen` causes my application to crash anyway, at a later as stage, as if doing this call kills my application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`popen` uses `fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html#ERRORS) which apparently [shouldn't be used in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179726/2436175). To see which processes are running probably the only safe way is to check in the `/proc` dir. More reading: [popen on android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910934/popen-on-android-ndk)